# Is there a way to build docker image from two jars such as each jar locates in it's own layer

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm using sbt-native-packager along with DockerPlugin to build an app.
This apps consists of two projects: one is changing frequently and another is almost static.
Build looks like this:

```
lazy val root = myProject("my-backend", ".")
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin).settings(dockerSettings: _*)
  .settings(dockerExposedPorts in Docker := List(80, 8080))
  .dependsOn(servicesProject, coreProject)
  ...
```

Is there a way to build a Docker image where each of projects (servicesProject, coreProject) will be in a separate layer?
In this case there will be no need to download static/core layer all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it manually, without the sbt-native-packager. You could use a Dockerfile to create a coreProject image that contains your core artifacts. Then create a different Dockerfile for the servicesProject that is based on the coreProject image and contains often changing artifacts. You can then rebuild the servicesProject image often and the download will be smaller.

Comment: Thanks for good advice. But in this case I should always remember to update coreProject image in case of changes.
It would be nice to have separate layers in one image so all updates occurs automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem and we haven't implemented a solution for this yet. There was [an attempt](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/pull/368) to solve it for single builds by splitting up dependencies in static and non-static and creating separate layers so the static layer is cached.

The SBT Native Packager API is capable of handling this use case. The basic idea is the following

- split your library dependencies in static and non-static
- create two *add commands* out of the `mappings in Docker` setting
- both *add commands* add to the same directory

Take a look at [the makeAdd method](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/docker/DockerPlugin.scala#L157-L160) and [mapGenericFilesToDocker](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/docker/DockerPlugin.scala#L244-L257), which essentially create the docker container content.

If you have a working solution, we'll be happy to add this an archetype autoplugin.